# Axios Z_BUFF_ERROR in NextJS SSR

Tags: next.js, axios, server-side-rendering, zlib

#### The issue

I have a NextJS app that prefetches some data from the API for SSR (using the same data fetch functions on the server and client side). On the client side it's working fine. On the server side (Vercel) I'm getting [this error](https://gist.github.com/almaron/f6a71b93f0713a97117ecb403231cc8b) .

#### Example Code

This is what returns the error

```js
const http = axios.create({ baseURL: apiURL() })
export const fetchProjects = (tags: string[] | number[] = [], page: number = 1 ) => async () =>
  (await(http.get(`${appConfig.PROJECTS_ENDPOINT}?${queryString({tags, page})}`))).data
```

Same as this

```js
export const fetchProjects = (tags: string[] | number[] = [], page: number = 1 ) => async (): Promise<any> => (
  axios.get(`${apiURL()}${appConfig.PROJECTS_ENDPOINT}?${queryString({tags, page})}`, {
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Accept-Language': 'en,ru;q=0.9',
    }
  }).then(response => {
    return response.data;
  }).catch(error => {
      console.error(error);
      throw error;
    })
)
```

replaced with this all works perfectly fine on both server and client

```js
export const fetchProjects = (tags: string[] | number[] = [], page: number = 1 ) => async () => (
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fetch(
      `${apiURL()}${appConfig.PROJECTS_ENDPOINT}?${queryString({tags, page})}`, {
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Accept-Language': 'en,ru;q=0.9'
        }
      }
    ).then(response => {
      response.json().then(data => resolve(data));
    })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
        reject(error);
      })
  })
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was fixed in the newest version of axios.